# Yii2 имя текущего контроллера в модуле

Tags: php, yii2, controller, модули

Есть базовый класс для всех модулей

```
namespace app\components;

use Yii;

class Module extends \yii\base\Module
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        var_dump(Yii::$app->controller->id); // null :(
    }
}
```

Все модули расширяются от него, т.е.

```
namespace app\modules\test;

class Module extends \app\components\Module
{
    //
}
```

Как мне получить название текущего контроллера в базовом классе модуля ?

```
Yii::$app->controller->id
```

возвращает null

Answer (score 2):

Ну для начала не

```
Yii::$app->controller->id
```

а

```
Yii::app()->controller->id
```

Тогда он выдаст тебе название контроллера.

**//UPD**

Ты вызываешь его из **init() модуля**. Что может дать тебе этот вызов, если он не значет какой контроллер у тебя сейчас.
Он и будет тебе всегда NULL показывать!

и если вопрос звучит именно так

> Как мне получить название текущего контроллера в базовом классе модуля
>   ?

то ответ никак. т.к. модуль не знает о контроллере ничего чтобы выдать какую-то информацию.

Comment: *Ну для начала не `Yii::$app->controller->id` а
`Yii::app()->controller->id` Тогда он выдаст тебе название контроллера.*  `Yii::app()->controller->id` это под первый Yii

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю самым простым решением будет создание еще одного класса от которого будут наследоваться все остальные, в котором можно делать операции с ид контроллеров.

```
class MainController extends yii\base\Controller { 
    // some... 
     public function beforeAction($event)
    {
         $ct = $event->controller->id; // current ctrl
         return parent::beforeAction($event);
    }
 }
```

А от него наследовать уже все остальные контроллеры

`class PostController extends MainController {   // do something... }`

Comment: вы не совсем поняли что я имею ввиду , поправил вопрос